# React calculateState method - how to show unchanged state?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have `calculateState` method in React component to check if state has changed or not:

```
static calculateState(prevState) {

    var state = ItemStore.getState().toObject()

    if (state && state.selectedItem && prevState && state.selectedItem.id === prevState.selectedItem) {
        return 
    }

    var result = {
      selectedItem: state.selectedItem
        ? state.selectedItem.id
        : null,
    }

    return result
}
```

What is returned if I use plain `return` without object? How to show that state is unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Function which does `return` with no arguments return undefined

```
(() => { return })()
// undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the result is processed like this:

```
const resultState = calculateState(prevState);
const finalState = {
  ...prevState,
  ...resultState,
};
```

Then you could `return state` or `return {}`.